# Vuejs 3 - Problem with data function inside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a list of projects which I get from an api. They get forwarded one by one to this component:

```html
<template>
    <button id="project-button" @contextmenu="handler($event)" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-1 ms-1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" :data-bs-target="`#${project.Name + project.ID}`">{{project.Name}}</button>
    <div :id="`${project.Name + project.ID}`" class="collapse">
        <button @click="setProjectId" id="add-object-button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-1 ms-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createObject">
            <b>Add Data Object</b>
            <i id="plus-icon" class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
        <DataObjects :dataObjects="dataobjects"/>
    </div>
    <CreateObjectModal @add-object="addObject" :projectId="projectId"/>
</template>

<script>

import DataObjects from './DataObjects'
import CreateObjectModal from './CreateObjectModal'

export default {
    name: 'Project',
    data() {
        return {
            dataobjects: [],
            projectId: 0,
        }
    },
    props: {
        project: Object,
    },
    components: {
        DataObjects,
        CreateObjectModal
    },
    methods: {
        setProjectId() {
            console.log(this.project.ID)
            this.projectId = this.project.ID
            console.log(this.projectId)
        },
        async addObject(objectName) {
            console.log(objectName)
            console.log("After adding object: " + this.projectId)
            console.log("Event arrived")
        },
```

Inside the data function I have an object which has the attribute projectId. When I click on the Add Data Object button a modal opens where the user can type in the name of the data object. The modal opens through the `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` attributes. Now in my click event for this button I can get the individual id of a project depending on which button I click. But the problem here is that I will need the specific id of a project inside my addObject function. The addObject function gets called when I click 'Ok' in my modal after the user types in a name. The logs show clearly that if I click on a button the different id gets set correctly but when I click 'Ok' from the modal and the AddObject function gets called then the id remains 1 which is the first id of the projects

I dont know if I am complicating things but I tried to send the id to my modal component which didnt work. The idea was to send it back to the addObject function via $emit. I am kinda stuck with this problem and hope someone can help me. Here is the Modal Component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="createObject" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">New Data Object</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input v-model="objectName" class="form-control" id="input">
                            <label for="input">Object Name:</label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <Button data-bs-dismiss="modal" @click="createObject" :text="'Save'"/>
                        <p>{{projectId}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import Button from './Button'

export default {
    name: 'CreateObjectModal',
    data() {
        return {
            objectName: '',
        }
    },
    props:{
        projectId: Number
    },
    methods: {
        createObject() {
            this.$emit('add-object', this.objectName)
        }
    },
    components: {
        Button
    },
    emits: ['add-object']
}
</script>
```

Comment: in your modal component you have `projectId: Number` - where comes that `Number` from?

Comment: can you share the full code of this?

Comment: @biberman It comes from the project component. There I have a component called `CreateObjectModal` where I pass the projectId in.